# Want to output my entered names by JOptionPane outside the loop, JAVA

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, joptionpane

Basically i want to enter the names as long as i don't cancel the InputMessageDialog, then i  want to asign my names to variable created before and print them out at the end in the MessageDialog. I was trying some stuff outside the loop but got the notificacion that "value 'names' is always 'null'"

```
    String names;
    while (true) {
        names = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "ENTER THE NAMES");
        if (names == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ENTRY CANCELED!");
            break;
        } else {
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOUR NAMES: " + names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty close to what you describe as your goal – the primary thing missing is that you need to keep track of the various values along the way, and print them at the end.

The code you posted will loop again and again asking for a single value (which you are storing into `String names` - a little confusing choice for variable name, since it contains only one name input). As you found, when the user hits the cancel button (to end the loop), it sets `names` to `null`. The final step shows a dialog box with the last value for `names` (which is always `null`).

Here's a program that:

- loops until the user hits the "cancel" button (which would set `input` to be `null`), or if they enter a blank value – this allows the user to exit by simply hitting return without typing anything
- adds all non-empty input values to a [`java.util.Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) – this is an arbitrary choice, use whatever data structure is appropriate for your program
- shows a final dialog with the contents of the set

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class t {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();
        while (true) {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter something");
            if (input != null && !input.isEmpty()) {
                values.add(input);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "all values: " + values);
    }
}
```

If I run with the following input:

```
one
two two
three three three
<blank>
```

Then the final dialog message is:

```
all values: [one, two two, three three three]
```

Note that a [`java.util.Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) doesn't necessarily return items in any specific order, it just happens to have worked out that way in this example.

Comment: Wow, thanks for describing everything step by step, i was also thinking about adding a sinple  array and put the names into it but i couldn't jump over it. Also i didin't practise the "HashSet", and the "Set" concept yet tho, but i will get into it and teach myself regarding to this. Thank you again.

Comment: Sure thing, glad it's helpful. Since you are the original question author, have a look at [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for steps you can take with posted answers.